# A razor page can't be found after create a new one

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages, startup, configure

I create "Pages" folder in my project and also an Index.cshtml in it with some simple code and after that run project to see if it is ok, continue then coding. but the browsers raise this error:
"This localhost page can’t be found" . my startup file consists of below code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
        services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.RootDirectory = "/Content";
        });

      }


   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseRouting();
    
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default" ,
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
  }
```

in my browser after my project run I use this route :"https://localhost:44332/index".
and Index is a razor page inside the Pages folder.

I appreciate if anyone help me.

---

[image]

I just created and my html just has one h1 tag to see if it work.

Comment: I had the same problem and using `Enable Razor runtime compilation` fixed the problem.

Comment: I install nuget package but it does not worked. @Mohi

Comment: Add a screenshot of the razor page folder structure to your question

Comment: I added it @MohammadAghazadeh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
   options.RootDirectory = "/Content";
});
```

to

```
 services.AddRazorPages();
```

And admin index page Route is based on your folders structure :

```
https://localhost:44332/admin/index
```

Because you use two types of routing `mvc` and `razor pages`, and if you just want to implement the admin part as a `razor oage`, it is better to create your admin files (pages) under the admin folder, not root the `Pages` folder  to prevent Route interference.

Answer (score 0):

This is causing ambiguity in your project. (You are using the wrong `RootDirectory`).

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.RootDirectory = "/Content";
});
```

Note that the best practice is to use Razor Pages whenever you need MVVM pattern which is for `Two-Way` Binding.